# I'm getting an SSL Error when sending email via Django

Tags: django, email, ssl, smtp

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:852)
```

This is what I see in the error log whenever I run my Django webpage. I'm hosting it with Apache. On the page I see a 500: Internal Server Error.

My Email config is as follows:

```
#Email settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'outlook.office365.com'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '****@**************.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
```

and my send_mail code is as follows:

```
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    '***************@**************.com',
    ['****@**************.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you are not using the correct port number.

You can search for SMTP settings of your email service on google.

**Kindly check for the correct port number of your email service.**

Comment: Thanks this solved it! I wasn't using the right settings for outlook

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with port number to '465'?

From docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_USE_TLS

For implicit SSL connections, port number is **465** and

for TLS it is 587

If that does not work, may be set to False and see if sending mail is working, let's debug further on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me. Make sure you go to Gmail > Account > Genereate App Password

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<YOUR EMAIL>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<YOUR APP PASSWORD CREATED BY GMAIL>'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```